# DDD read text messages from file

Tags: properties, domain-driven-design, message

I have my text validation messages in a properties file. How would you consider getting the message from the key? A domain service interface implemented by the infraestructure? Or would the implementation live in the domain too?

In the red book, text messages are literal, when passed to exceptions for example. They belong to domain.

But what if we deal with keys of a messages.properties file? How would you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the messages are part of the domain itself. Think about who will drive the changes to the messages. Will it be domain experts or marketing/UX people indicating that the particular message should be altered to convey the meaning better to customers?

If you had to create, for example, a new B2B client, do you anticipate that some messages would have to be changed? Does it mean that the domain has changed?

I would advise keeping the exceptions in the domain as independent from the external representation as possible. So, instead of saying `throw new PaymentProcessingException("Insufficient funds")` consider `throw new InsufficientFundsPaymentProcessingException()`. Then you could translate the specific exception into a proper message using the infrastructure service at the representational edge of your application.

Comment: Dou you mean the application layer would catch the exception and will pass the text message to the client (UI)? Or is it the client who does that job?

Comment: The former. The application layer would do the translation using the messages from a properties file.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand what you mean. The getting of the message from the key is not a particular job of the domain being modeled, it is a cross cutting concern. My fault was considering it as a domain service instead of an app service. But I think that in both cases, the final custom message can be be setted up by whoever people is reponsible of that job, marketing people, domain expert or whoever else. They just have to configure the properties file.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I meant. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, you helped me, thank you very much. I think your approach is ok. I asked this question cause I've read some articles that say text messages can be considered part of the model, as they use ubiquetous language concepts and talk about business. There's a debate about it, there are people who consider they belong to the domain, and other people who think they belong to the UI.  Vaughn Vernon in the Red Book consider them part of the domain (they are string literals passed to the exception in the domain model)

Comment: Do you always create custom domain exceptions? For example, when checking arguments you don't use standard java IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: I separate issues with validation of the input (usually in the command handlers) from the issues with incorrect domain situations. Usually, IllegalArgumentException would be thrown early in the processing of the command. Most of the time I use domain exceptions or events to represent issues like insufficient funds for processing of the payment.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. In my case it would be more annoying, as I check the arguments in the domain objects too. In my domain I have operation validation exceptions (like your insufficient founds) and arguments exceptions thrown (usually in setters). I'm thinking about create custom exceptions for these too. Besides that, I follow notifcation pattern when validating operations, so that my domain exceptions have a list of errors (one error = key + context args). I'm struggling about consider argument exceptions apart or to integrate them as custom operation exceptions too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: at the end I've used a mixture of answer from Oleg and message keys. 
What I've done are custom exceptions (DomainException) where I've added a custom field with the key of the message (at the end they're domain exceptions, they could/must be customized). Every exception has its own value.  Where I handle the exception I just add the code as a message response. Somewhere later, where the response is handled, I ask a service to translate the key.

Suggestions are welcome if this reveals not as good as it looks (for me).

Comment: Hi... your approach is similar to the one I was implementing. But in my case I didn't add the key of the message to the exception. In my case the domain gets the message from the key of a properties file, and creates the exception with the message. The properties file would be a configuration file where you put the messages you want for each key. This file would be configurated by the people reponsible of it

Comment: In other projects where I didn't use DDD , I did the same than you, I added the key to the exception and the controller catched the exception and read the properties file to get the message from the key of the exception.

Comment: Ahhh, now I also full undestand the answer of Oleg: a custom Exception, without keys inside, being part of the Domain layer is (must be, it's more correct) totally agnostic about the messages service that belongs to the service/application layer. Hence, the type of the exception instead of the key that it contains is meaningful for the message to publish.
Actually it's a better implementation than mine. 
Never stop learning, it's my motto ;)

Comment: Yeah that is. I did it in some project in the past too. I didn't add a key field to the exception. The key of the message was the name of the exception itself.

Comment: But if you want to add context info in the message, I'm afraid that you will have to add a field to the exception for that. I added an Object array to store the values when you raise the exception. This values are the ones that you format the text message with.

Comment: @choquero70 yes, the context is put into the exception itself as it is the domain concept. In my example, it could be `requestedAmount` and `availableAmount` fields that the application service could use to format the specific message for a client